# java regex extract not working?

Tags: java, regex

What am i missing??

This is the 'dataStoreConstructor' I am passing to the method code below -

```
url='https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/26.0',corpnet_prodnet='Corpnet'
```

```
  public void registerDataStoreInRepository(String dataStoreConstructor) throws DragonException{
    String constructorPattern = "url='([^']*?)',corpnet_prodnet='([^']*?)'";
    System.out.println(constructorPattern);
    System.out.println(dataStoreConstructor);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(constructorPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(dataStoreConstructor);

    SalesforceDataStore sfDataStore = new SalesforceDataStore.Builder(this, matcher.group(1), matcher.group(0)).build();
  };
```

This is the output I see -

```
url='([^']*?)',corpnet_prodnet='([^']*?)'Exception in thread "main" 
url='https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/26.0',corpnet_prodnet='Corpnet'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:485)
    at com.dragon.dictionary.salesforce.SalesforcePlatform.registerDataStoreInRepository(SalesforcePlatform.java:63)
```

Comment: it works fine here http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/39

Comment: sorry for the typo in the output - 

Why is this causing a 'No match found' exception then?

Comment: The pattern looks good, however the lazy quantifiers are useless since you use a negated character class: `'([^']*)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
if (matcher.find()) {
    SalesforceDataStore sfDataStore = new SalesforceDataStore.Builder(this, matcher.group(1), matcher.group(0)).build();
}
```

You've forgotten to tell the matcher to go and find something :-)

Answer (score 3):

Regex is fine. Just call :

```
matcher.find()
```

once before calling `matcher.group()`.Your problem will be solved.